# How to increase timeout for a long ajax response?

Tags: javascript, ajax, post

I am have the follow ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: drupalSettings.ajaxFiltersRequest, 
    timeout: 9000000,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    type: "POST",    
    dataType: "json",    
    data: JSON.stringify({
    'mobileDescriptions' : 'jsDescriptions',
    'dbColor' : dbColor
    })
}
```

It is giving me a 502 Proxy Error. The proxy server could not handle the request. I've checked the logs on the server and the data are being retrieved. It is just taking a loong time since there are a lot of data. Is there any solution for an error like this?

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a default `timeout`. What happens if you remove `timeout: 9000000` from your object?

Comment: @AndroidNoobie it's still the same... Same error is encountered.

Comment: This is an error on the server-side. I don't think it has anything to do with jQuery or a request timing out.